# Scraping multiple lists from a website.

Tags: c#, post, parameters, request, webclient

I'm currently working on a web scraper for a website that displays a table of data. The problem I'm running into is that the website doesn't sort my searches by state on the first search. I have to do it though the drop down menu on the second page when it loads. The way I load the first page is with what I believe to be a WebClient POST request. I get the proper html response and can parse though it, but I want to load the more filtered search, but the html I get back is incorrect when I compare it to the html I see in the chrome developers tab.

Here's my code

```
    // The website I'm looking at.
    public string url = "https://www.missingmoney.com/Main/Search.cfm";

    // The POST requests for the working search, but doesn't filter by states
    public string myPara1 = "hJava=Y&SearchFirstName=Jacob&SearchLastName=Smith&HomeState=MN&frontpage=1&GO.x=19&GO.y=18&GO=Go";
    // The POST request that also filters by state, but doesn't return the correct html that I would need to parse
    public string myPara2 = "hJava=Y&SearchLocation=1&SearchFirstName=Jacob&SearchMiddleName=&SearchLastName=Smith&SearchCity=&SearchStateID=MN&GO.x=17&GO.y=14&GO=Go";

    // I save the two html responses in these
    public string htmlResult1;
    public string htmlResult2;

    public void LoadHtml(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            htmlResult1 = client.UploadString(url, myPara1);
            htmlResult2 = client.UploadString(url, myPara2);

        }
    }
```

Just trying to figure out why the first time I pass in my parameters it works and when I do it in the second one it doesn't.

Thank you for the time you spent looking at this!!!

Comment: What do you mean by *"the html I get back is incorrect"* ?

Comment: The html I get back doesn't have the tables that I need in order to parse though

Comment: I would suggest using `Selenium` rather than `WebClient`.

Comment: @JacobLoncar, may be when you first visit the page in your Internet browser you're getting cookies and they are being attached in the post. If that's the case, and you don't attach those cookies in your C# code, you're not going to get same result. In your internet browser open inspection tool and go to Network tab, capture a post that worked and make sure you're sending same post in C# code.

Comment: @derloopkat thanks for the info I'll give it a shot!

Comment: @derloopkat that did the trick thank you!!!

Comment: use two clients. One for each page so you do not have to keep on refreshing the main page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply forgot to add the cookie to the new search. Using google chrome or fiddler you can see the web traffic. All I needed to do was add

```
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "cookie");
```

to my code right before it uploaded it. Doing so gave me the right html response and I can now parse though my data.

@derloopkat pointed it out, credits to that individual!!!